# Combine Click with hover

Tags: jquery, click, hover

I need to get this code to work so when the item is clicked the mouseout doesn't fade out the element.

```
$('.link1').hover(function(){
    $('#image1').fadeIn();
},function(){
    $('#image1').fadeOut();
}).click(function(){
    $('#image1').css('display','block');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.link1').hover(function(){
    $('#image1').fadeIn();
},function(){
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
    if(!clicked) $('#image1').fadeOut();
}).click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    $('#image1').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: I now need to dynamically add the id of image and this doens't seem to work. I've just tried to get the first part to work. $('#image-map area').hover(function(){
        var linkClass = $(this).attr("class");
        var linkClassID = '#' + linkClass;

        linkClassID.stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    },function(){
    var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
    if(!clicked) $('#image1').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }).click(function(){
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    $('#image1').css('display','block');
    $('#image1').siblings('display','none');
    });

Comment: @Clint - that's a bit hard to read. Perhaps it deserves a separate question?

Answer (score 0):

Add some attribute so you can check on it.

```
$('.link1').hover(function(){
  if(!$('#image1').is(':visible')) $('#image1').fadeIn();
}, function(){
  if(!$(this).attr("clicked")) $('#image1').fadeOut();
}).click(function(){
  $(this).attr("clicked", true);
  $('#image1').css('display','block');
});
```